# LibGDX - Accessing assets from desktop executable jar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, libgdx

This is how my tree structure looks in eclipse:

[image]

For example, this is how I load shaders:

```
// Eclipse side-effect of linking assets, assets are copied in bin folder
if (Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.Android) {
    dirHandle = Gdx.files.internal("data/shaders");
} else {
    // ApplicationType.Desktop ..
    dirHandle = Gdx.files.internal("./bin/data/shaders");
}
```

When I make executable jar, it looks like this:

[image]

How should I reference assets or is there a way to preserve that structure in Eclipse?

Comment: The "./bin" work-around is a hack for desktop development builds your data is reachable via a directory on the classpath.  I think the bare "data/shaders" should work with all the data in a .jar file....

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that I add the hack with `dirHandle = Gdx.files.internal("./bin/data/shaders");`, because I was unable to list a directory on desktop. So in case of jar it is useless anyway.